# partial integration

Tags: integration, analysis

I have a short question about partial integration.
If I want to determine an integral of the form $\int f'gdx$, the formula for partial integration is:

$$\int f'gdx=[fg]-\int fg'dx$$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts .

Sometimes it is useful to apply the integration rule twice, for example if $g=x^2$ and then you have to apply partial integration on $\int fg'dx$.

My question is: To calculate $\int f'gdx$, are both possibilities ((1),(2)) allowed:

(1) $\int fg'dx=[Fg']-\int Fg''dx$

(2) $\int fg'dx=[f'g]-\int f'g dx$?

Comment: If you do (2) you get back to where you started.

Comment: Equation (2) is wrong... How did you get?

Answer (score 1):

No. equations 1 & 2  are not valid.
IBP is basically the reverse or the re - arrangement of the product rule.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the rule as many times as you want/can, because you are just starting an integral afresh every time.

$$\int f'g\,dx=fg-\int fg'\,dx$$ can indeed be followed by

$$\int fg'\,dx=Fg'-\int Fg''\,dx$$

where $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$.

You could also integrate on the other factor, with

$$\int fg'\,dx=fg-\int f'g\,dx$$ but this is of little use.

---

So a "second order" rule can be written

$$\int f''g\,dx=f'g-fg'+\int fg''\,dx.$$